# Using "android:enabled" in styles.xml

Tags: android, android-view, android-styles

I'm trying to disable some views (about 5-6) thru **styles.xml**. For this, I created a style with following item:

```
<item name="android:enabled">false</item>
```

And used such style for every view I wanted to disable. However, I still can use those "disabled" views (BTW They doesn't even look like disabled at all) - clicking/touching. 
I decided to use styles.xml because I didn't want to bother (call `view.setEnabled(false)`) with every view every time I want do disable it.

So is there any way to make **"android:enabled"** work in **styles.xml** or I need  to disable each view by myself?

Answer (score 0):

So, as far as I can see, Android provides ability to set "enabled" not in all views. For example, you can't actually set `"android:enabled"` for a SeekBar with using auto-complete (there would be no variants for "enable"), however you can still type it in views xml-body or just copy-paste this attribute - project would be compiled without any errors or warnings at that place, but there would be no actual result - view may still be available in the app. That thing is kinda strange behavior, because for every view you can set `setEnabled(...)` from the code and that would work.

So, if you have a lot of similar views that you want to disable/enable by default (and you failed with using `<item name="android:enabled">false</item>` in *styles.xml*) the best solution would probably be overriding the view you want and adding custom additional attributes to manage the state.